# understand the need of "\v" in substitution

Tags: substitute

I have a following line:

```
   <a href="/episodes/show-invisibles/"> Show invisibles: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/
```

..and I have a `:s/\v^[^\>]+\>\s//g` substitution command which changes this line to:

```
Show invisibles: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/
```

As I understand the regular expression of this substitution, then `^[^\>]+\>\s` part will match one or more whatever character(except `>`) from the beginning of the line until `>` and whitespace character appear. However, why is the `\v` needed? According to vim manual:

```
Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
'0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"
```

However, why is this needed in this particular case?

Comment: `[^\>]` means except '\' and '>', even with `\v`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case, using `\v` doesn't make much difference

```
s/^[^>]\+>\s//g
```

is perhaps cleaner than using the very magic modifier

---

Consider swapping two words:

```
s/\(\w\+\) \(\w\+\)/\2 \1/
```

With `\v` it is much cleaner and readable

```
s/\v(\w+) (\w+)/\2 \1/
```

---

So, it might be a habit to always use `\v` and it is closer to regular expression syntax used in `perl`, `sed -r`, `awk` etc